# What does the "three dots" mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I stumped on something in Typescript today.

[image]

What does the three dots mean in this type?

I can't find anything that explain this at all.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
let all: { readonly [key: string]: (...args: any) => any } = {
  form,
  metadatas_reducer,
  loader_reducer
}
const combinedReducer = combineReducers(all)
```

Comment: Check this article https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754 Hope this will explain as you expect

Comment: Another link: https://dev.to/sagar/three-dots---in-javascript-26ci

Comment: This is not a spread operator, this is typescript syntax

Comment: Why does your image show text on top of other text? Is this some kind of tooltip/popup? If so, what are you hovering over, and do you know what its actual type is?

Comment: @JLRishe Hi, I just edited the picture so now you can see it better

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran Thank you. Can you tell us what the inferred type of `all` is? I suspect this may not be a syntactical feature but rather a convention used in the hover-over tooltips.

Comment: @JLRishe I agree—not actual syntax but notation of the editor. I think it might just be shorthand for "many" or something, similar to the rest operator, but hard to tell exactly

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran, can you please share the syntax in text instead of the screenshot?

Comment: Do not confuse with `...` (ellipsis) in vscode tooltips with the actual meaning of spread operator in typescript. In tooltips it just means, there is something more but for brevity it is not displayed.

Comment: It would also help to know what editor/IDE this is.

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran, can you click on that three dots? If it is ellipsis, then the hidden codes will be shown if you click on it.

Comment: @JLRishe this is vscode, also I added the code above. I don't understand why it show as threedots there.

Comment: @Lokesh As Yasir said, I can't click on it so it's not an ellipsis

Comment: Those are just mere text ellipsis, it won't expand. In vscode *tooltips* you will never see any expandable one. There are other places too where vscode shows text ellipsis (especially when generic types are used deep down the hierarchy of the classes/interfaces) and it just means something more (nothing to do with typescript syntax)

Comment: That means that the function is variadic and can accept any number of arugments

Comment: @Lokesh, I see, but its weird that I cannot expand it, so with the three dots I cannot see what is there actually. An annoying ellipsis...

Comment: @Lokesh: I see, but its weird that I cannot expand it, so with the three dots I cannot see what is there actually. An annoying ellipsis...

Answer (score 5):

VSCode will sometimes replace types with an ellipse for some reason, possibly to shorten them. In this specific case, the build output is the following.

```js
export declare const combinedReducer: import("redux").Reducer<import("redux").CombinedState<{
    readonly [x: string]: any;
}>, import("redux").AnyAction>;
```

This is not the spread operator.

Answer (score 4):

This is the TypeScript spread operator:
https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/spread-operator/

Which can also destructure incoming arrays and dictionaries, so you can merge two dictionaries by doing this:

```
> a = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> b = [4,5,6]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
> [a,b]
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
> [...a,...b]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```